# Outlook: make a rule that acts when number of (unread) mails in a folder exceeds a treshold

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

We're looking to perform a series of action every time the number of (unread) mails in a folder exceeds a certain limit.

Example:

- When the number of mails in a folder > 10000, mail the assistant to clean it up.
- When the number of unread mails in a folder > 10, mail the admin that the robot probably stopped working
- ...

In a perfect world this would be a serverside rule, not needing a client to be online to run.

We could use RPA to write this, but are checking if there are "lighter" alternatives, aside from clientside VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not feasible to be realized in Outlook using rules or other built-in options. Reference: [How to Get Warned If There Are Too Many Unread Emails in Your Outlook Inbox](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/get-warned-many-unread-emails-outlook-inbox/)